# SharePoint Apps File not Found

Tags: sharepoint-addin

When I install apps from the Microsoft App Store, I get the following issue:

> Sorry, there was a problem with Artezio SP Picture Library Photo Wall- File Not Found.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with you 3rd party app **Artezio SP Picture Library Photo Wall**.
No issues on sharepoint side. You can check with this App owners who published this app on Microsoft store.